# Swing: column-flow layout manager?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm looking for a `LayoutManager` that will allow me to show a set of components in a container (e.g. a JPanel), in columns, roughly as follows.

- The container's width is an input constraint.
- The container's preferred height is a function of the width, and is either:

  - the minimum height needed to get the components to fit within the width, when laid out in more than one column.
  - the minimum height needed to get the components to fit in a single column.
- The components will be placed in a newspaper-column order, from top to bottom and then from left to right.

Here's an example (low-tech text display) showing 13 components. If they can fit in 3 columns, they would look like this:

```
Foo1    Foo6     Foo11   
Foo2    Foo7     Foo12
Foo3    Foo8     Foo13
Foo4    Foo9     
Foo5    Foo10
```

If that's too wide, they'd look like this:

```
Foo1    Foo8 
Foo2    Foo9  
Foo3    Foo10 
Foo4    Foo11 
Foo5    Foo12
Foo6    Foo13
Foo7
```

And if that's too wide, they'd look like this:

```
Foo1     
Foo2      
Foo3     
Foo4     
Foo5    
Foo6    
Foo7    
Foo8
Foo9
Foo10
Foo11
Foo12
Foo13
```

Is there a pre-existing LayoutManager that I can use or subclass to do something like this?

---

edit: this is very close to [this other question about vertical layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495094/swing-layout-vertical-flow), but that layout has the component height being the constraint, and mine has the component width being a constraint.

Answer (score 2):

One other component that admits this kind of layout is [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), which includes a `VERTICAL_WRAP` that "Indicates a *newspaper style* layout with cells flowing vertically then horizontally." Depending on your needs, a suitable `ListCellRenderer`, mentioned [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), may be suffice.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look into GribBagLayout
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

With gridbag layout knowing the size you can set how many components you would have in a particular row.

but if i am not mistaken shouldnt gridlayout do exactly what you want.

lets go with the simple labels. 
 if the size*2 of the label is longer than the width, then it will show only 1 label per row. and so on.

here is an example which should clear it up

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GridLayoutDemo implements ActionListener{
    JTextField j1;
    JTextField j2;
    JFrame f;
    public void show(){
        j1=new JTextField("x dimention");
        j2=new JTextField("y dimention");
        f=new JFrame();
        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        JLabel l2=new JLabel("abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvw");
        JLabel l1=new JLabel("abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvw");
        JLabel l3=new JLabel("abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvw");
        JLabel l4=new JLabel("abcdefghijklmnoqrstuvw");
        JButton b=new JButton("new size");
        b.addActionListener(this);

        p.add(l1);
        p.add(l2);
        p.add(l3);
        p.add(l4);
        p.add(j1);
        p.add(j2);
        p.add(b);
        f.setSize(400, 200);
        f.add(p);

        //f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GridLayoutDemo g=new GridLayoutDemo();
        g.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x=Integer.parseInt(j1.getText());
        int y=Integer.parseInt(j2.getText());
        f.setSize(x,y);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but GridBagLayout and other grid-oriented layouts have a static grid size. I need to figure out the grid size dynamically.

Comment: Did you try your own demo? It flows horizontally, not vertically. (FYI there's not much point in calling setSize() when you can just do that interactively by resizing the JFrame yourself)